# connect two serial port instances from a (ruby) program to a physical serial port (usb0)

Tags: linux, serial-port, jruby

I have a program (jruby with rxtx on ubuntu-machine) which opens 2 seperate serial ports. Is it possible to connect both of them to one hardware port i.e. ttyUSB0, or alternatively to a virtual serial port (I have a program to simulate the hardware)?

Is there something like a software repeater/hub to connect 2 serial ports? I checked socat but this one only connects 2 ends with one another. I have read [hint for vde2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082722/how-do-i-create-virtual-ethernet-devices-in-linux) and [hint for slip/slattach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890505/socat-tunnel-ip-through-tty) but could not find a solution.

No socat specialists out there?

Comment: I would recomend to check if there is any Java libs available. Because you using JRuby, calling Java from your code is very easy.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did not want to change my jruby code, I rather like to solve this external, like prepare ports for use...

Answer (score 0):

I finaly could solve this problem only with port ownership in the java class. No way with socat, I think because of the framing problems.

I created an ownership handler like in

[Managing Serial Port Ownership (in rxtx)](http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/managing-serial-port-ownership-in-rxtx/)

in jruby it looks like

```
class SerialOwnershipHandler
include CommPortOwnershipListener

def initialize serial_port
  @serial_port = serial_port
  @id = serial_port.id
  @port_name = serial_port.port_name
end

def ownershipChange type
  case type
    when CommPortOwnershipListener::PORT_OWNED
      p @id.to_s + "  OwnershipListener: got the port for " + @port_name.to_s
      #break
    when CommPortOwnershipListener::PORT_UNOWNED
      p @id.to_s + "  OwnershipListener: just lost it's port ownership for " + @port_name.to_s
      #break
    when CommPortOwnershipListener::PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED
      p @id.to_s + "  OwnershipListener: someone is asking port ownership for " + @port_name.to_s
      @serial_port.close
      #break
  end
end...
```

In my serial port class initialize method I call

```
    @serial_ownership_handler = SerialOwnershipHandler.new self  ## implements CommPortOwnershipListener
    @port_id.add_port_ownership_listener @serial_ownership_handler
```

Only disadvantage. You cannot have more than one open line. You have to always close one connection before opening anohter one (the one who requests the port)